# ASP.NET postback causes AJAX exception

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a basic asp.net webform that handles events via standard postback. On this page, I also have an AJAX call to a WCF service that is managed by the JavaScript proxy generated by a ScriptManager control. The problem I'm having is this: sometimes a user fires the AJAX request then fires a postback immediately afterward, which is causing the AJAX call to throw an exception. It appears to be a timing issue: if you wait until the AJAX request is complete, then postback, all is well. I *thought* I was doing an asynchronous request, so I'm not sure why I'm getting the error. Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if async postback is in progress using isInAsyncPostBack property of PageRequestManager and postback is generated by this Button then cancel this request

http://www.atulverma.com/2010/06/how-to-disable-subsequent-submit-button.html

Comment: Thanks, Joe, that's helpful, but what I was really wondering is why the AJAX call cares about postback at all? Seems like if the WCF method it's calling doesn't return anything, the postback shouldn't cause any problems, know what I mean?

Comment: I agree, but it doesn't know that it will not alter the page when returning to the client. It just knows it has the potential to do that. Ugly, I know....